# Cannot output <xml> tag when overriding the XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've created my own XmlTextWriter from another example, so that I can remove namespaces.

```
public class NoNamespaceXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    //Provide as many contructors as you need
    public NoNamespaceXmlWriter(System.IO.TextWriter output)
        : base(output) { Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented; }

    public override void WriteStartDocument() {}

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        base.WriteStartElement("", localName, "");
    }
}
```

When I use this it works OK but for some reason it skips the `<xml ... >` `</xml>` tags. WriteStartDocument() is never called.

I can't specify settings properly since they have a private setter and usually you use the static method XmlWriter.Create which I cannot override. I tried overriding the settings themselves, but no avail:

```
public override XmlWriterSettings Settings
{
    get { return new XmlWriterSettings() {OmitXmlDeclaration = false}; }
}
```

my code to serialize is:

```
using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (NoNamespaceXmlWriter xmlWriter = new NoNamespaceXmlWriter(textWriter))
    {
        xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, p);
    }
    xml = textWriter.ToString();
}
```

Any idea how I can get the xml tag to appear, or why it's disappearing?

Comment: What is `p` (can you include the class definition?) and what is the output using a 'normal' XML writer compared to this one?

Comment: p is just a class with serializable fields. A normal XML writer outputs `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the Settings being null, or default, and it's just treating it as omit=true because I've added a manual call to WriteStartDocument() and removed the override and it has put the `<xml>` declaration in

Comment: OK, I was slightly confused by you saying it missed `<xml>...</xml>` tags (implying part of the content) rather than the XML declaration.  Clear now!  I'm guessing there's a reason you can't just remove the namespace values from whatever `p` is?

Comment: I can replicate your issue, but it's resolved by ensuring that `WriteStartDocument` calls the base implementation (it *is* called).  See this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0axeGo).  But you say it's never called?

Comment: It's never called in the first place - I put a breakpoint on it but it is never hit.

I've solved it by just making a manual call to it.

Comment: Ok.  It's not going to be possible to advise any further because the issue can't be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal here is to remove the namespaces from the serialized XML, I'd suggest an easier way: You can specify XmlSerializerNamespaces with empty namespace as illustrade in the sample application below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player player = new Player() { Id = 102, FirstName = "Danny", LastName = "TopScorer", AverageGoalsPerGame = 3.5, TotalGoalsScored = 150 };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Player));
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings);

        XmlSerializerNamespaces xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, player, xns);

        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int TotalGoalsScored { get; set; }
    public double AverageGoalsPerGame { get; set; }
}
```

It will output:

```
<Player>
  <Id>102</Id>
  <FirstName>Danny</FirstName>
  <LastName>TopScorer</LastName>
  <TotalGoalsScored>150</TotalGoalsScored>
  <AverageGoalsPerGame>3.5</AverageGoalsPerGame>
</Player>
```

Otherwise the Player element would look like this with the defaults:

```
<Player xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```